# Openstack Glance Configutarion on HTTPS RESTAPI + Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl, apache2, openstack, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to install openstack Using ssl certs i am able to run keystone (on port 5000) but when i try to connect to glance api (port 9292) it fails it is only accessible with http not https i feel like keystone works because it has seperate configuration file in
"/etc/apache2/site-enabled/keystone.conf"
but glance(and other services) has different story you create endpoints via openstack cli (apache2) and add this configuration to the end of nginx.conf

```
stream {
    upstream glance-api {
        server 127.0.0.1:9292;
    }
    server {
        listen <public_ip>:9292 ssl;
        proxy_pass glance-api;
    }
    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/hoodadcloud.ir/fullchain.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/hoodadcloud.ir/privkey.pem"; }
```

when i add this to configuration it failes to restart nginx service by running "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" i get

```
controller nginx[44254]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to <public_ip>:9292 failed (98: Unknown error)
controller nginx[44254]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to <public_ip>:9292 failed (98: Unknown error) 
controller nginx[44254]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to <public_ip>:9292 failed (98: Unknown error) 
controller nginx[44254]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to <public_ip>:9292 failed (98: Unknown error)    
controller nginx[44254]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to <public_ip>:9292 failed (98: Unknown error)  
controller nginx[44254]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind() 
controller systemd[1]: nginx.service:Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Subject: Unit process exited DefinedBy:systemd
```

i am 90% sure it's because port 9292 work on http not on https
using ubuntu server 22.04 LTS minimal

openstack user list works fine (keystone)

openstack image list (glance)

```
Failed to contact the endpoint at https://hoodadcloud.ir:9292 for discovery. Fallback to using that endpoint as the base url. 
Failed to contact the endpoint at https://hoodadcloud.ir:9292 for discovery. Fallback to using that endpoint as the base url. 
The image service for : exists but does not have any supported versions.
```

net-state -ntlp

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9292          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      292411/python3
```

Comment: The problem is probably that glance is configured to listen on all interfaces and is not only bound to the loopback interface. When you then attempt to configure nginx to listen on your public IP-address that same port number, port 9292 is already in use and can't be used by nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to diya
the problem is port 9292 or any other openstack services is Listening on all ip addresses (0.0.0.0) the solution is to set

> bind_host = 127.0.0.1

in /etc/glance/glance-api.conf then the nginx proxy will start without problem and you can resolve api

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9292          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      292411/python3
```